# let $f$ is a function and satisfy in the equation $\cos(f(x))+ \frac{8}{\pi^3}(f(x))^3 +2f(x)=1+x$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, derivatives

let $f$ is a function and satisfy in the following equation :$$\cos(f(x))+ \frac{8}{\pi^3}(f(x))^3 +2f(x)=1+x$$

find  $2f^{\prime}(0)+f^{\prime}(\pi)$ .

I find $f(0)=0$ and with derivation ( if we let $f$ is continuous in $0$ and $\pi$) we have :$$(\cos(f(x))+ \frac{8}{\pi^3}(f(x))^3 +2f(x))^{\prime} =-f^{\prime}(x)\sin(f(x))+3f^{\prime}(x) \frac{8}{\pi^3}(f(x))^2 +2f^{\prime}(x)=1$$ and so we can compute $f^{\prime}(0)=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Do the same business, showing first that $f(\pi)=\pi/2$.

Comment: @arugula . yes .but how we can  compute $f$ in $\mathbb{R} $?

Comment: The question you asked was not how to compute $f$ in $\mathbb{R}$, it was only how to do a very specific computation. If instead you wish to ask how to compute $f(x)$ for every real value of $x$ then the best you can do with an equation like this is some kind of numerical approximation. But, that's not the question that you asked in your post.

Answer (score 1):

HINT : I suppose that it is an academic exercise. If so, the equation to be solve is not too complicated. In the first equation, all difficulty to solve it for $f(x)$ comes from the $\cos(f(x))$. One can guess that this $\cos$ term is nul for $x=\pi$ , making the equation easy to solve.

So, we try $f(\pi)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ :
$$\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})+ \frac{8}{\pi^3}(\frac{\pi}{2})^3 +2\frac{\pi}{2}=1+\pi$$
By luck, it agrees. Thus :
$$f(\pi)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
I suppose that you can continue.

Answer (score 1):

Define $g(x) = \cos x + \frac 8{\pi^3}x^3 + 2x$. Since $g'(x) = \frac{24}{\pi^3} x^2 + 2 - \sin x > 0 $, $g$ is strictly increasing, continuous and unbounded on $\mathbb R$. Thus, it is bijective. We can conclude that $g(f(x)) = 1 + x$ not only has a unique solution $f$, it is differentiable and bijective on $\mathbb R$. Its derivative is given by $$f'(x) = \frac 1{g'(f(x))}.$$

Thus, we need to find out $f(0)$ and $f(\pi)$. We could just as well guess the values. Let $x_0, x_1$ be such that $f(x_0) = 0$, $f(x_1) = \pi/2$. We have $$1+x_0 = g(f(x_0)) = g(0) = 1\implies x_0 = 0, \\
1+x_1 = g(f(x_1)) = g(\pi/2) = 1 + \pi \implies x_1 = \pi. $$

Notice that it is important that we know that such $x_0$ and $x_1$ exist in the first place by surjectivity of $f$. It now follows that $$2f'(0)+f'(\pi) = \frac 2{g'(0)} + \frac 1{g'(\pi/2)} = 1 + \frac \pi{\pi+6}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the graphic of the functions
$$\begin{cases}h(x)=\cos(f(x))+ \dfrac{8}{\pi^3}(f(x))^3 +2f(x)\\g(x)=1+x\end{cases}$$ we verify that $$x=0\Rightarrow h(x)=1\Rightarrow f(0)=0\\x=\pi\Rightarrow h(x)=1+\pi\Rightarrow f(\pi)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
On the other hand
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{-\sin(f(x)+\dfrac{24f^2(x)}{\pi^3}+2}$$ It follows
$f'(0)=\dfrac 12$ and $f'(\pi)=\dfrac{\pi}{6+\pi}$ from which the answer.

Comment: Why we can use derivation ? We don't know that $f$ is continuous .

Comment: The fact is that $g(x)=1+x$ is obviously continuous and it is equal to $h(x)$. Besides $h(x)$ is injective and increasing so for all $x$ you can find the preimage of $1+x$ by $h(x)$ which is not other that $f(x)$.